# c++ Question with displaying text between two array variables

Tags: c++, computer-science

I always seem to have this problem when I want to display two variables of an array in one iteration of a loop, I'm wondering if there is a nicer way of displaying the array.

The code works if I change ++i to i+1 but I'm wondering why that happens, and I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do what I want. The error says unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int players = 0,rounds=0;
    bool winnerFound=false;
    cout << "Welcome to my tournament match maker\n";
    cout << "Enter the number of participants in the tournament: ";
    cin >> players;
    rounds=players/2;
    string *pNames = new string[players]; //dynamically allocate 
    for (int i = 0;i < players;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of player " << i + 1<<":";
        cin >> pNames[i];
    }
        random_shuffle(&pNames[0],&pNames[players]);
        for(int i=0;i<rounds;i++)
        {
           cout<<pNames[i]<<" vs "<<pNames[++i]; //
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: *"The code works if I change ++i to i+1 but I'm wondering why that happens"* You'r increasing `i` in `for(int i=0;i<rounds;i++)` and then you're also increasing it in `pNames[++i]`. You're increasing it twice in each run through the loop, surely that's not intended.

Comment: It is intended, I want to display two different strings and not only have 'i' go up by one because itll show a name too many times if I don't.  I don't see a difference from that code and this code that works                                      for(int i=0;i<rounds;i++)
 {
   cout<<pNames[i]<<" vs "<<pNames[i+1];
   i++;
 }
 return 0; which has got me questioning things

Comment: Please, note that there are two increments: pre-increment (`++i`) and post-increment (`i++`). The former increments value of `i` and returns the new value. The latter returns the value of `i` and increments afterwards (before next sequence point).

Comment: Yeah thats why i put ++i and not i++, and thats why im wondering why theres an issue.

Comment: @MikeCalicoder: for example, you will get 3 players, in the second loop you will get `i = 2`, and when you will `++i`, you're trying to access `pNames[3]`, but `pNames` have only 3 values (from 0 to 2).

Comment: @Raffallo No, because the loop runs until `rounds`, and 3/2 == 1, so the loop will run only once, he will not try to access an extra element but rather miss the last one.

Answer (score 1):

For the tips, I think it is better to use a STL container instead of a raw array. `std::array` or `std::vector` for example. You can change the declaration of `pNames` as follows:

```
std::vector <std::string> pNames(players);
```

Your problem is that you iterate only until `rounds`. You don't want that, you want to loop over all players, not only half of them.

To make your code work, you need to write:

```
for(size_t i = 0; !pNames.empty() && i < pNames.size()-1; ++i)
{
    std::cout << pNames[i] << " vs " << pNames[++i] << std::endl;
}
```

But I think it is a bad way to modify `i` from inside the loop, you better have to directly increment `i` by two in the loop statement. This will give:

```
for(size_t i = 0; !pNames.empty() && i < pNames.size()-1; i+=2)
{
    std::cout << pNames[i] << " vs " << pNames[i+1] << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, if you have only one player or any odd number of players, you will miss the last one (because you need two opponents to make a vs).

I hope it can help.

Comment: why check for `pNames.empty()` when the loop would abort with condition being `0 < 0-1` with i = 0 and size = 0?

Comment: @FalcoGer Because with a `size_t` aka `unsigned long long`, 0-1 will underflow. And I didn't use an `int` in order to use the proper types the vector is expecting (and avoid either warnings for automatic conversion or `static_cast`s).

Comment: To be more clear, 0-1 equals -1 with `signed` types. But with `unsigned` types, it underflows and usually equals the max positive value the corresponding type can hold. So the condition will never be `false`.

Comment: I said `size_t` is a `unsigned long long` but it depends of the platform. But usually, `size_t` is defined as `unsigned` (`unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, ...)

Comment: Thank you the i+=2 is what is was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int players = 0,count=0;
    cout << "Welcome to my tournament match maker\n";
    cout << "Enter the number of participants in the tournament: ";
    cin >> players;
    string *pArray = new string[players]; //dynamically allocate
    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0;i < players;i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name of player " << i + 1<<":";
        getline(cin, pArray[i]);
    }
    random_shuffle(&pArray[0], &pArray[players]);
    for (int i = 0;i < players;i++)
    {
        cout << ++count << ": " << pArray[i] << " vs " << pArray[i + 1] << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any critiques?

Comment: You do a lot of strange things to be honest. Read my answer, it will provide you some tips **and** the solution to your problem.

Comment: since you want to increment at the end of the loop anyway, you might as well increment by 2 in the loop header. generally you'd use a for loop for such scenarios where the entire control can happen in the for instruction

Answer (score -1):

Firstly `i++` and `++i` are different.
`i++` increments after returning the value and
`++i` increments before returning the value of the result.

It would be more readable if you incremented your i in the for loop by two and then not have a side effect when asking for the array value. And of course you need to check if i is valid at this point

```
for(int i=0; i < players-1; i += 2)
{
    // check if valid.
    // with odd numbers of players, the last remaining player will be dropped.
    cout << pNames[i]<<" vs " << pNames[i+1]; // no side effect.
                                                  // In a for loop
                                                  // all increments should happen in
                                                  // the loop header.
}
```

Comment: This method is wrong, let's consider 10 players. At the first iteration, you will display 0 and 1, but at the second iteration, you will display 4 and 5, you miss 2 and 3.

Comment: I see, but I'm not the one who downvoted your answer so I connot remove it.

Comment: But there is still an error, you should iterate while `i < players-1`.

Comment: @Fareanor how about you remove your downvote and i delete the post since you already answered?

Comment: I have never downvoted you. This is not me, so I cannot remove the downvote. But yes, I already gave the solution and was the first to answer :)